# Evaluation of the Gamma and Digamma Functions

Tags: calculus, limits

Problem: Evaluate:

> $$\dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{a+b+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1-b}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{a+2}{2})}\bigg (\psi\bigg ( \frac{a+b+1}{2}\bigg )-\psi\bigg ( \frac{a+2}{2}\bigg )\bigg ) \bigg |_{a=0,b=1}$$

This had come up while solving an integral.  Upon plugging in $a=0,b=1$, I got However, this does not give the correct answer. A suggestion was to take the limit as $b\to 1$. I was unable to understand why this was done. Is it because when we cannot evaluate a function $f(x)$ at $x=a$, we take $$lim_{x\to a} f(x)$$

Could somebody please tell me how to solve this problem? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugging in $a=0$ leads to no problems.  However, $b=1$ leads to an indeterminacy, as the differences in the $\psi$'s are zero while the $\Gamma \left ( \frac{1-b}{2} \right )$ yields infinity.  Let $b=1+\epsilon$ and use the relation

$$\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin{\pi z}} $$

Thus

$$\Gamma \left ( -\frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) \Gamma \left ( 1+ \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) = -\frac{\pi}{\sin{(\pi \epsilon/2)}} $$

or, as $\epsilon \to 0$,

$$\Gamma \left ( -\frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) \approx -\frac{2}{\epsilon} $$

Thus, in this limit, the original expression is equal to

$$-\frac12 \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left [\frac{\psi \left ( 1+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \right ) - \psi(1)}{\epsilon} \right ] = -\frac14 \psi'(1) = -\frac{\pi^2}{24}$$